# What grammatical material describes the construction to be + ed?

Tags: grammar

I have few sentences which are hard to my understanding. I don't understand grammatical pattern for building it. Can you give me hiperlink where it was described?

**Problem sentence:**

At least twenty chemical elements ***are known to be required*** to support human biochemical processes by serving structural and functional roles as well as electrolytes.

**Optional**: can you explain me type of grammatical connection in this sentence with **by** (processes **by** serving)?

Comment: You're parsing the sentence slightly wrong.  "processes by serving" isn't one phrase.  Think of it as "support (noun phrase) by (verbing)".  *Processes* here is actually a noun, which is part of the noun phrase "human biochemical processes".

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is "[Scientists] know that at least twenty chemical elements are required..."

By using the passive voice ("*they are known to be*"), the writer avoids saying exactly *who* knows this, but it has to refer to biochemical scholars.

---

Those elements support *human biochemical processes*: by serving structural and functional roles.